# Strange results while checking the memory layout of a c program using size command in linux

Tags: c, linux, size

When i check the memory layout of following c program, using command `size program_name` in linux, i get data = 552, bss = 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now, after adding a uninitialized variable, i still get the same result, data = 552, bss = 8. **I was expecting bss = 12 here.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If i add a variable initialized to a value, i get what i expected, data = 556, bss = 12

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int b = 10;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, if a declare a pointer and make it point to the initialized variable, i get data = 568, bss = 8, **which i don't understand why.**
(To me, it seems like both pointer and uninitialized variable have been added to initialized list!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int b = 10;
int * c = &b;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please clarify what is happening here?

Comment: maybe in the first case, `expecting bss = 12`, compiler it optimizing the _unused_ and _unreferenced_ variable `a`.

Comment: but then the same optimization should happen to second case as well? or it won't?

Comment: @Eregrith Where is that happening?

Comment: @Eregrith where `+2` increase?

Comment: @Eregrith it's `568`, `8+8`, `16`...so it fits the logic, no?

Comment: @SouravGhosh omg I'm so blind ... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DATA segment holds all initialized data. It is contained in the executable image. As `b` is initialized to a specific value it is contained in the DATA (in the image).

The BSS segment holds all unitialized vaiables. It is just a number contained in the image and the loader will allocate the memory for it and initialize it to zero. Thus `a` is contained in this number (contained as the number of bytes to allocate for it at load time).

`c` is not initialized to a value that can be placed in the DATA segment. Hence it is contained in the BSS segment, however, at load time, the loader must resolve this address and then initialize `c` to where `b` is actually placed in memory.

Note: as a result of this strategy, `a` and `b` are not contiguous in memory. This can make debuging memory problems harder. Probably debugging versions of the program will have them contiguous to be able to debug the program.

Comment: But the result i got (given in the question statement), doesn't appear to be according to what you said. That's why i asked the question. Even after creating a uninitialized variable, there is no change in memory layout. If i consider this to be an optimization, the same doesn't happen when we also have an initialized variable (they both appear in their respective segments, bss and data, giving correct output).

Comment: Hishant, have you tried the compilations with all optimizations disabled? Could you change return(0) into return(a) so you are sure it is not optimized away? Check he assembler code too to make sure a is loaded into ax for the return. We must get to a well defined state.